# Cannot install and the code is not working: apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

I am using a full fresh installed Kali Linux rolling edition. And please be specific to me while explaining the matter because I am very new-be in the world of Linux. My host OS is Ubuntu 15.10.

[image: apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11]
[image: apt-cache]
[image: apt-cache]
[image]

Comment: Which version of VirtualBox you are using? Can you please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/780674/edit) your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy virtualbox

Comment: That would be version 5.

Comment: Please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images (see [How do I save terminal output to a file?](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814)).

Comment: "Kali Linux rolling edition" = off topic.  We only support official Ubuntu releases.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and easy answer:

First install the needed dependencies you need to build the modules:

```
apt-get install linux-headers-amd64 dkms
```

Then install the gues additions with:

```
sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

this will take care of everything normally. The VirtualBox Guest additions are not within the Kali repository so you cannot install them with `apt-get`, but since you mounted the additions CD anyways (as seen in your screenshot) this above command will take care of everything.

Comment: I tried that too, but it said.. : "Building the main Guest Additions Module fail! (Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong) But what do I d

Comment: Sorry..But It says Unable to find package linux-headers-generic. Actually what's the problem? :(

Comment: @ Videonauth Look...I added a new photo as an answer.

Comment: @FarhanUzumakiTahmid Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your guest is missing DKMS support , this would allow it to easily build the modules for the virtualbox guest.  On ubuntu you can install guest tools from these packages, not sure if Kali does this the same way.

```
sudo apt-get update      
sudo apt-get install dkms virtualbox-guest-dkms
```